# Laravel rule to update unique column if it exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a table called positions which user_position is a unique number. I only want to update a record if the new user_position does not exist in the table or is equal to the current user_position. How do I express such a rule? My current rule below does not allow updating.

```
$rule=[    
    'user_position' => 'required|integer|unique:positions'
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer and more details can be found on the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique

So following the docs my rule becomes this

```
$rule=['user_position' => 'required|integer|unique:positions,id']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `updateOrCreate()` method:

```
$positions = Position::updateOrCreate(
    ['user_position' => $userPosition],
    ['name' => $newName, 'age' => $newAge]
);
```

> You may also come across situations where you want to update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. Laravel provides an `updateOrCreate` method to do this in one step.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required)

> **Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:**
>
> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check.
>   For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the
>   user's name, e-mail address, and location. Of course, you will want to
>   verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only
>   changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a
>   validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of
>   the e-mail address.

Here is how you could achieve this using required ignore.

if you are using  [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation) for validation you could do something like this. assuming the url is something like /positions/1/edit for editing and positions/create

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
....

public function rules()
{
    //position id
    $id = $this->route()->parameter('position'));
    //or like this if id is in parameter as 2nd segment
    //$id = $this->segment(2); 

    return [
        'user_position' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('positions')->ignore($id)
        ]
    ];
}
```

if you are not using request classes for validation

```
 //get id of parameter positions
 //using Illuminate\Http\Request $request;
 $id = $request->route()->parameter('position'));
 //or using helper
 // $id = request()->route()->parameter('position'));

 $rule=[ 
     'user_position' => [
           'required',
           Rule::unique('positions')->ignore($id)
      ]
 ];
```